# The square of the solution of the equation...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The square of the solution of the equation

$x\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{8 - 3\sqrt{7}} - \sqrt{8 + 3\sqrt{7}} = 0$

is equal to: ...

$x\sqrt{7} + \sqrt{8 - 3\sqrt{7}} - \sqrt{8 + 3\sqrt{7}} = 0$

$\implies x\sqrt{7} = \sqrt{8 + 3\sqrt{7}} - \sqrt{8 - 3\sqrt{7}}$

$\implies 7x^2 = \left(8 + 3\sqrt{7}\right) + \left(8 - 3\sqrt{7}\right) - \underline{2\sqrt{\left(8+3\sqrt{7}\right)\cdot\left(8-3\sqrt{7}\right)}}$

$\implies 7x^2 = 16 - 2\cdot\sqrt{64-63} = 14$

$\implies x^2 = 2$

I know how to do all the steps up to the part where the underlined section comes into play, can someone please explain where does this come from. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The formula $(a-b)^2=a^2+b^2-2ab$  is used.

Here, $a=\sqrt{8+3\sqrt7}$ and $b=\sqrt{8-3\sqrt7}$.

Answer (score 4):

Note that $$(a-b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab $$

Your confusion is the      $$-2ab = -    \underline{2\sqrt{\left(8+3\sqrt{7}\right)\cdot\left(8-3\sqrt{7}\right)}} $$

Answer (score 2):

Alt. hint:   show first that $\;\sqrt{8 \pm 3\sqrt{7}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(3 \pm \sqrt{7}\right)\,$, then no squaring is needed.